# Functions, identity functions

Tags: functions, relations

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, ... , n\}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $F$ be the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$. Let $R$ be the relation on $F$ defined by:

for all $g, f \in F, fRg$ if and only if $f(i) \lt= g(i)$ for some $i \in A.$ Let $I$<sub>A</sub> : $A \to A$ be the identity function on $A$ defined by $I$<sub>A</sub>$(x)$ = $x$ for all $x \in A$.

How many elements $f \in F$ are there so that $I$<sub>A</sub>$Rf$? Explain.

**My attempt:**
We know that identity function reverses what the function did. So, since identity function here is defined as $I$<sub>A</sub>$(x)$ = $x$, then there are n elements?

Comment: Are you certain that the statement of this problem is correct? Note that for any function $f: A \to A$, we have that $I_A(1) = 1 \leq f(1)$, as $f(1) \in \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n \right\}$. Therefore, every function would fit this criterion...

Comment: Thanks @JuliaJackson Yes the statement is correct, what about the opposite of it, how many elements $f \in F$ are there so that $fRI$<sub>A</sub>?

Comment: I'll leave you to figure that out, but here's a hint: the solution to that question is quite similar to the solution to your first question.

Comment: @JuliaJackson so for this question, there are $n^n$, and for the opposite, there is only $n^1$, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $I_A\,R\,f$ means that there is some $i\in A$ with $i = I_A(i) \le f(i)$. So the functions $f$ such that $I_A\,R\,f$ is *false* are those functions $f\in F$ such that $i>f(i)$ for all $i\in A$. How many such functions are there?

Comment: thanks - but A is not finite, it is infinite, n elements, right?

Comment: Right, $A$ is finite - that's what I said.

Comment: sorry, I meant, A is not finite.

Comment: But it *is* finite! It has $n$ elements.

Comment: So, |F| functions? in other words every function.

Comment: Yes, but why? (What must be true of $f(1)$?) Also, what is $|F|$?

Comment: And also, it doesn't matter if $A$ is finite or infinite - the argument regarding $f(1)$ still works.

Comment: |F| is number of elements. because, the identity function is defined as $I$<sub>A</sub>(x) = x, and relation is $I$<sub>A</sub>$(i)<= $f(i), for some $i \in A$. correct?

Comment: Yes, but explicitly, how many are there if $A$ is finite? (How many choices are there for $f(1)$? For $f(2)$?)

Comment: There are $n$ choices?

Comment: Right. So how many functions are there altogether?

Comment: @how about the opposite of it? $fRI$<sub>A</sub>? There is only 1, where n=1, correct?

Comment: since there are n elements, there are $2^n$ functions.

Comment: Since there are $n$ elements, and each element can have $n$ possible images, there are $n^n$, not $2^n$, functions.

Comment: And finally, for the opposite problem, I think you can work this out yourself given this discussion. (Think about $f(n)$).

Comment: Thanks, for opposite there are $n$ functions.

Comment: No, $n^n$, just like in the first case.

Comment: Oh so, $n$ of them are onto, but there are $n^n$ ?

Comment: $n!$ are onto (think of it as permutations of the set $A$), while the total number of functions is $n^n$ (each member of $A$ has $n$ possible images).